# How to calculate unique combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Let's suppose that we have three variables: $xyz (n=3)$. We need to calculate how many unique combinations we can make. So in this case, you can simply get the answer without using any formulas: $xy, xz, yz, xyz$. So there are $4$ unique combinations. But how do you calculate it with some kind of formula when it gets more complicated? So for example, $4$ variables $wxyz$. Now you have $wx, wy, wz, xy, xz, yz, wxy, wxz, wyz, xyz, wxyz$ ($11$ combinations). And how do you do this when you have even $10$ variables? How do you do this?

Comment: Well, a set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets, and you don't want the empty set or sets with exactly one element so...

Comment: You've missed out a lot of combinations. There are 6 combinations of 4 things in pairs, not 4.

Comment: For $n=4$ you skipped $yz$ but otherwise you are good.

Comment: @WeatherVane Which combinations did I miss then with n=3

Comment: @WeatherVane I dont really get what you are saying. I dont see any missed combinations

Comment: To be fair, you had skipped $yz$ from the $n=4$ case but then you added it back in an edit.

Comment: You did see, and added it, and then denied it.

Comment: @lulu I know, but I was talking to Weather Vane because he is talking about n=3. I don't see any missed combinations regarding n=3

Comment: In any case, it is correct now.  Do you understand the (strong) hint in my first comment?

Comment: @lulu To remove the sets with exactly one element, you calculate 2^3-3, so 5. But the answer is 1. How do you remove the 'empty sets'. I don't get why there would be any empty set in the first place?

Comment: @Dzoooks To represent combinations.

Comment: The answer for $n=3$ is not $1$, it is $4$ as you point out in your question.  There is one empty set so you also have to subtract $1$.

Comment: In general, you have $2^n-n-1$.

Comment: @lulu My bad, was a typo. What do you mean by empty set though? Why is there an empty set if you calculate 2^n

Comment: The empty set is a subset of every set.  Hence one of those $2^n$ corresponds to the empty set.

Comment: Think of it this way:  there are $2^n$ total subsets.  $n$ of those have only one element, $1$ has no elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A set with $n$ elements has exactly $2^n$ subsets.  Here we do not want the empty set, nor do we want any set with exactly one element.  Thus the answer is $$2^n-n-1$$

Comment: Hi, I've almost certainly got something wrong here, but your answer doesn't make sense to me with OP's example. In the 4-set example (wxyz), there are 6 unique combinations. But where n is 4, your formula would give (2^4) - 4 - 1  =  16 - 4 - 1  = 11, which is more than 6. Have I made a simple mistake here?

Comment: @Lou  Not following.  The OP works the $n=4$ case and gets $11$ combinations, just as in the formula I gave. Where does your $6$ come from?

Comment: Ah, my fault - I was thinking about the number of unique *pairs* of variables, not the number of unique combinations.

Comment: Out of interest, do you know how you would calculate the total number of pairs? That's what I started googling for when I came across this question :)

Comment: Never mind, [found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859430/how-do-i-get-the-total-number-of-unique-pairs-of-a-set-in-the-database)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add visualization to my answer (and support Lulu's reply). I tend to think on subgroups in terms of binary numbers. Think about it this way: in how many ways you can have 'sub groups' of the followings ABCD?

```
    A|B|C|D
    -------
0   0 0 0 0
1   0 0 0 1
2   0 0 1 0 
3   0 0 1 1
4   0 1 0 0 
5   0 1 0 1
6   0 1 1 0 
7   0 1 1 1        changed from 1111 to 0111.
8   1 0 0 0 
9   1 0 0 1
10  1 0 1 0
11  1 0 1 1
12  1 1 0 0
13  1 1 0 1
14  1 1 1 0
15  1 1 1 1
```

You will note that you can have 2^4=16 possibilities from sub grouping of ABCD and if you wish to eliminate 0000 and exclude only 1 letter (there are 4 possibilities) so you're left with 16-4-1=11.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful